# Java program calculates averages. How do I display highest average?

Tags: java, loops, average, mean

I have a java program that takes the scores of 4 players and computes each player's average score when -1 is inputted. At the end of the program I need to display the highest average score out of the 4 averages, however I cannot figure out how to do this, can you guys set me in the right direction? The program looks like this when it is run: (I have also attached my code) I cannot use anything but loops.

Player 1

Enter your score: 100

Enter your score: 90

Enter your score: 80

Enter your score: 70

Enter your score: -1 (when -1 is inputted, the average score is calculated)

Average Score = 85.00

Player 2

Enter your score: 90

Enter your score: 90

etc.

etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BowlingScores
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
      double score = 0;
      double totalScore = 0;
      double count = 0;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int player = 1; player <= 4; player++){
         System.out.printf("\nPlayer %d\n", player);

        do{
           System.out.println("Enter Your Score: ");
           totalScore = totalScore + score;
           score = input.nextDouble(); 
           count++;
         } while (score != -1);

         if (score == -1){
          count--;
          System.out.printf("Average Score = %.2f\n",totalScore/count);
          count = 0;
          score = 0;
          totalScore = 0;
         }    
      }    
   }
}
```

Comment: You are adding -1 to the score. I would do "`if score == -1 break`" before "`totalScore+=score; count++`"

Comment: Sorry I should have also mentioned we are not allowed to use breaks.

Comment: Then you need to use it in the while condition. (updated my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of the highest average in another variable. Then in your `score == -1` condition check to see if the current average is higher than the highest average, and if so make current the new highest. Then after your for loop you could print out the highest average.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a copy of the highest at the top of your code like this `double highest = 0` then in your for loop have a way to replace it if the current average is higher.

```
if(score > highest){
      highest=score;
}
```

Then at the -1 you can either reset it to 0 or keep it going.

Answer (score 0):

Take average of all 4 players and store into one array. Then check for the largest number in array.

```
double[] highest = new double[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    highest[i] = totalScore/count;
}

if(highest[0]>highest[1] && highest[0]>highest[2] && highest[0]>highest[3])
    System.out.println("highest" + highest[0]);

else if(highest[1]>highest[0] && highest[1]>highest[2] && highest[0]>highest[3])
    System.out.println("highest" + highest[1]);

else if(highest[2]>highest[0] && highest[2]>highest[1] && highest[0]>highest[3])
    System.out.println("highest" + highest[2]);

else System.out.println("highest" + highest[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Double> allAverages = new ArrayList<>();
    double score = 0;
    double totalScore = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int count = -1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int player = 1; player <= 4; player++) {
        System.out.printf("\nPlayer %d\n", player);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Your Score: ");
            totalScore = totalScore + score;
            score = input.nextDouble();
            count++;
        } while (score != -1);

        avg = totalScore / count;
        System.out.printf("Average Score = %.2f\n", avg);
        allAverages.add(totalScore / count);
        score = 0;
        totalScore = 0;
        count = -1;
    }

    System.out.println("The highest is : " + Collections.max(allAverages));

}
```

Here a list of the modifications I did to your code to get it working :

- The variable count now start at -1, so there is no need to do count-- when we exit the loop.
- I've added a List that keep a track of all the averages.
- I've removed the validation `if(count == -1)` after the loop as the only way to exit the loop is to have count == -1 so we already know it is the actual value.
- To retrieve the maximum of all averages, I use `Collections.max(allAverages)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    double bestScore = 0;
    int bestPlayer = 1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int player = 1; player <= 4; player++){
        System.out.printf("\nPlayer %d\n", player);
        int count = 0; // does not need to be double
        double totalScore = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Your Score: ");
            double score = input.nextDouble();
            if (score != -1) { 
                totalScore += score;
                count++;
            }
        } while (score != -1);

        double averageScore = totalScore / count;

        if (averageScore > bestScore) {
            bestScore = averageScore;
            bestPlayer = player;
        }

        System.out.printf("Average Score = %.2f\n", averageScore);
    }

    System.out.printf("Best Average Score = %.2f, best player = %d\n", bestScore, bestPlayer);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. This one works the best since it doesn't use anything we aren't allowed to use such as arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a variable to record the top average score every time as in `topAverage`  in my example below. The code is same as your's except I changed the variable names for my readability.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {
        double currentScore = 0;
        double totalScore = 0;
        int numScores = 0;
        double averageScore = 0;
        double topAverage = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Score");
                currentScore = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                totalScore = totalScore + currentScore;
                numScores += 1;
            } while (currentScore != -1);
            numScores-=1;
            totalScore+=1;
            averageScore = totalScore / numScores;
            System.out.println("Average Score is " + averageScore);
            if (topAverage < averageScore) {
                topAverage = averageScore;
            }
            currentScore = 0;
            totalScore = 0;
            numScores = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Top Average is " + topAverage);
    }
```

**Edit**

**@Andrei Nikolaenko** posted the same answer before me, so consider that answer, I am adding this edit because I want to mention that my browser did not refresh on time to show me that the answer has already been posted.